# Applications when minimized do not appear on the panel on Fedora 11

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-11

When I try and open a terminal on Fedora and minimize, the window title does not appear on the panel. Any other application like rdesktop as well doesn't appear either.

Answer (score 2):

Have you accidentally removed the Window List object from the panel? Right click on the panel, select Add to Panel... then select Window List

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel and go to the 'add applets to the panel' search for 'Window list' and enable it, if it is not possible just click on the 'reset all' button. This will set to default settings.